# .htaccess file unable to redirect

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a website which has many pages.

When I search my web my domain name, other pages

career.html
contactus.html

are also shown in the result (as they are crawled).

Lets say i have career.html page and when i click on this in the searched results instead

of my career page i want the user to be redirected ti my index page.

For this i have an .htaccess file. It has the following code

```
#htaccess 
Redirect ^careers.html http://www.mydomainname.com/
```

This is what i have read online, that will take the user to my home page. But this is not working for me.

What else needs to be done to redirect the user to homepage.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^careers.html$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this all that i have to write in .htaccess file? I copy pasted the same code in my htaccess but this is not working for me. Sorry but this is new for me!!

Comment: Also you need to enable a rewrite module for you apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `Redirect` directive that doesn't accept regex. You can use it look this:

```
Redirect /careers.html /
```

Or else you can use `RedirectMatch` with regex support:

```
RedirectMatch "/careers\.html$ /
```